# How do i use setinterval in javascript to display the status of the Importing task?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my project i'm using Setinterval to display the importing status of the excelsheet to database. 
ie., if excelsheet contains 100 records means my status message is ,
    Row 1 0f 100 Rows Inserted
    Row 2 of 100 Rows Inserted..

But if the row contains any empty value means i need to get the error details and add that too in the status message. So It works with some issues.

My javascript function is as follows.

```
 function ImportFormSuccess(taskId) {
        endform();
    Tid = taskId;

            try {
                intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: rootDir + "Import/Progress",
                        data: { id: Tid },
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.split(',').length > 1) {
                                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + data.split(',')[1] + "<br/>";
                                updateMonitor();
                            }
                            else {
                                Message = data;
                                updateStatus();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }, 100);

            }
            catch (err) {
                txt = "Error Description" + err.Message + "</br>";
                txt += "Click Ok to Continue. . .";
                alert(txt);
            }

        function updateMonitor() {
            $('#monitors').attr("class", "");
            $("#monitors").html(Message + "<br/>" + ErrorMessage);
        }

        function updateStatus() {
            $('#status').attr("class", "");
            $("#status").html(Message);

        }
```

View Code is:

```
<div id="monitors" style="padding: 2px;width:500px;height:150px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid;></div>
```

If i run the project and start the import means,
 it displays the following:

```
Row 5 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 5 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 5 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 5 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 7 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 7 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 7 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 7 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 10 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 10 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 10 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 10 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 15 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 15 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 15 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
```

But i need it to be printed only once..
ie.,

```
Row 5 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 7 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 10 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
Row 15 Insert Failed. Row Contains Empty Value
```

any help???

Comment: Can you use regex .match(/\((-?\d+)\)/) to extract only number from your message and assign to a global variable. so before printing this $("#status").html(Message) you can verify with the assigned global variable is same as before. if not matching then print else return false.

Comment: Is it possible that 100ms is simply too fast and you are hitting the service while is still processing the same row?

Comment: @Tallmaris 100ms is an assumption only.. but it depends upon the row length and data.. thats why it stucks..

Comment: Consider use a flag to not ask to the server before the last request ends. You should use a flag before `$.ajax` and in your callback too.

Comment: @Anna.P Can u send me that code plz..

Comment: @VitorCanova can u send me that sample code plz

Comment: @JasperManickaraj I made a JsFiddle for you. Cannot test but I think it will just work: http://jsfiddle.net/VtZU6/

Comment: @VitorCanova thats not working..

Comment: @JasperManickaraj maybe its because the variable scope. Try window.isBusy instead.

Comment: @VitorCanova that also wont work

Comment: @JasperManickaraj Sorry. I woke up stuppid. I forgot the most important, the IF. Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/VtZU6/1/

Comment: I would put the ajax call in a separate function and use `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()` to call that function again when the request completes (maybe with a stop condition to avoid going on forever).

Comment: @VitorCanova that also wont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fixed this issue.

I use match function to check whether thar errormessage is already exist or not?

```
 if (data.split(',').length > 1) {
     if (!ErrorMessage.match(data.split(',')[1])) {
           $("#monitors").show();
           ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + data.split(',')[1] + "<br/>";
           updateMonitor();
           }
     }
```

Thanks for all who is helped me a lot for my question.. Special Thanks to @Anna.P, @TallMaris, @VitorCanova

Answer (score 1):

```
globalVar = "";

Message = data;
                         var rowVal = data.match(/((-?\d+))/)[1];

                         if(globalVar == "")
                         {
                             globalVar = rowVal;
                             updateStatus();
                         }
                         else 
                         {
                             if(globalVar != rowVal)
                             {
                                 updateStatus();
                             }
                         }
```

Try like this

Answer (score 0):

Following from comment, I would try something like this:

```
function ImportFormSuccess(taskId) {
    endform();
    Tid = taskId;

    try {
        callServer();
    }
    catch (err) {
        // ...snip...
    }
}

function callServer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rootDir + "Import/Progress",
        data: { id: Tid },
        success: function (data) {
            // your code here
        },
        complete: function () {
            // if not 100% (or something similar)
            setTimeout(function () { callServer(); }, 100)
        }
    });
}
```